# Set-AIPAuthentication -DelegatedUser

Tags: azure, user-permissions

I am trying to run the "Set-AIPAuthentication" command unsuccessfully.

I think it is because of the "DelegatedUser" parameter where I have put an Azure AD account but this account is not a priviledged one.

Do I have to specify a Global Admin for that parameter?

I followed this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azureinformationprotection/set-aipauthentication?view=azureipps

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What error was reported?

Comment: Thanks Carl Zhao.

The reported error is as follows:


Set-AIPAuthentication : Unable to authenticate and setup Microsoft Azure Information Protection
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AIPAuthentication -AppId "b9775265-fe57-44e0-9" - ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : AuthenticationError: (:) [Set-AIPAuthentication], PowershellException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.InformationProtection.Powershell.AIP.Commandlets.SetAIPAuthenticationCmdLet